# Query find ne in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593947f95ccc81692670e6b4"),
    "user1" : 100,
    "user2" : 4,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "sender" : 100,
            "datetime" : ISODate("2017-06-08T12:50:01Z"),
            "body" : "hiii 0"
        },
        {
            "sender" : 100,
            "datetime" : ISODate("2017-06-09T12:50:01Z"),
            "body" : "hiii 1"
        },
        {
            "sender" : 4,
            "datetime" : ISODate("2017-06-10T12:50:01Z"),
            "body" : "hiii 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am looking to find all the messages where one of user1 or user2 is 4 and list only those messages where sender!=4.

looking for output :

```
"user1" : 100,
    "user2" : 4,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "sender" : 100,
            "datetime" : ISODate("2017-06-08T12:50:01Z"),
            "body" : "hiii 0"
        },
        {
            "sender" : 100,
            "datetime" : ISODate("2017-06-09T12:50:01Z"),
            "body" : "hiii 1"
        }
```

Tried this

```
db.chat.find({ $and:[
 { $or : [ {"user1":4},{"user2":4} ] },
 {"messages.sender": {$ne :4}}
]}).pretty()
```

but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.aggregate` and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

```
db.chat.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [{"user1": 4}, {"user2": 4}]
    }
  },
  {"$project": {
    "user1" : 1,
    "user2" : 1,
    "messages": {"$filter": {
                      input: "$messages", 
                      as: 'message', 
                      cond: {$ne: ['$$message.sender', 4]}
                }
          }
  }}
])
```

To return only *message count* you can use this

```
db.chat.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [{"user1": 4}, {"user2": 4}]
    }
  },
  {"$project": {
    "user1" : 1,
    "user2" : 1,
    "messageCount": {
      $size: {
        "$filter": {
          input: "$messages",
          as: 'message',
          cond: {$ne: ['$$message.sender', 4]}
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or if you want to return all `messages` and *message count* then can use this query

```
db.chat.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [{"user1": 4}, {"user2": 4}]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "user1": 1,
      "user2": 1,
      "messages": {
        "$filter": {
          input: "$messages",
          as: 'message',
          cond: {$ne: ['$$message.sender', 4]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      user1: 1,
      user2: 1,
      messages: 1,
      messagesCount: { $size: "$messages" }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks Also, how will be the query change if i am looking for count only?

Comment: message count ? @QuizMaster

Comment: Yes the message count

Comment: you can use `$size` of message array after filter on next project stage `cont: { $size: "$messages" }`

Comment: @ShaishabRoy Or you can just use `$size` in front of the `$filter`. You should also use `$addFIelds` in modern versions since you do not need to specify the fields that are already there.

Comment: @ShaishabRoy can you please write the complete query for count.
Also, by count i am refering to number of rows returning by your 1st query.

Comment: @ShaishabRoy i am looking for row count of 1st query and not the message.... i am sorry i mentioned wrong earlier

Comment: would you please update your question with what your expected output? not clear about row count @QuizMaster

Comment: db.chat.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [{"user1": 4}, {"user2": 4}]
    }
  },
  {"$project": {
    "user1" : 1,
    "user2" : 1,
    "messages": {"$filter": {
                      input: "$messages", 
                      as: 'message', 
                      cond: {$ne: ['$$message.sender', 4]}
                }
          }
  }}
])

Lets say above query returns 2 rows, so i want output as 2 .

Comment: added this stage `{$group: {_id: null,count: {$sum: 1}} }` after `$project` stage

Comment: @ShaishabRoy Thanks Buddy

Answer (score 0):

```
db.demo.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
             $or:[{user1:4},{user2:4}]
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: "$messages"
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $match: {
               'messages.sender':{$ne:4}
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $group: {
              _id:{_id:'$_id',user1:'$user1',user2:'$user2'},
              messages:{$addToSet:'$messages'}
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

The above mentioned aggregate query executes below mentioned stages of aggregation in pipeline

- $match operator matches documents where value of either user1 or
  user2 is equal to 4.
- $unwind operator splits messages array into seperate document for
  each value contained in messages array.
- $match operator filters messages in which sender object is not equal 
  to 4.
- $group operator groups documents according to values of _id field and
  pushes messages into an array